# Run python function from command-line - invalid syntax due to full file path

Tags: python-3.x, command-line, filepath

I try to run a python function from command-line:

```
H:\myfolder\python.exe -c "from P:\myproject\myscript import myfct; myfct(1,2)"
```

An error occurs with this message:

```
P:\myproject\myscript ...
 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It works fine without the folder path:

```
H:\myfolder\python.exe -c "from myscript import myfct; myfct(1,2)"
```

The script should preferably run from other directories as well. Double backslash does not solve the problem as also stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155755/dealing-with-backslash-as-a-command-line-argument-in-python). As far as I can judge, it's not a problem of [directory change](https://superuser.com/questions/546280/why-do-i-get-this-error-when-i-specify-a-path-in-the-windows-command-prompt). How do I have to write the command string which contains the full file path?

The directory `P:` is a mapped network directoy. Is this a problem?

I'm using `Python 3.9.5` on `Windows 10 Pro`.

Comment: Paths in an `import` statement are not valid python syntax.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path